# How do I fix an error for giveaway command

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a giveaway command for one of my servers, but it doesn't seem to work, and I honestly don't know what the issue is.

My code:

```js
if (command === "giveaway") {
    var arguments = args.join(` `).split(`,`)
    const time = Number(arguments[0])
    const type = arguments[1]
    const winners = Number(arguments[2])
    const channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    const prize = arguments[4]
    var duration
    if (type === "m" || type === "minute" || type === "minutes") {
        var duration = time * 60000
    }
    if (type === "h" || type === "hour" || type === "hours") {
        var duration = time * 3600000
    }
    if (type === "d" || type === "day" || type === "days") {
        var duration = time * 86400000
    }
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("New Giveaway")
        .setColor(`RANDOM`)
        .addFields(
            { name: "Duration", value: `${time} ${type}`, inline: true },
            { name: "Winners", value: `${winners}`, inline: true },
            { name: "Prize", value: `${prize}`, inline: true },
        )
        .setDescription(`React with  to enter the giveaway.\nHosted by ${message.author.username}`)
    message.channel.send(embed).then(sentEmbed => {
        sentEmbed.react("")
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (reactions.cache.get("").count <= 0) {
            message.channel.send("Not enough people reacted for me to draw a winner")
            return
        }
        let winner = (m) => m.reaction.cache.get("").users.cache.filter((u) => !u.bot).random();
        channel.send(`Congratulations ${winner} You just won the **${prize}**!`
        );
    }, duration);
}
```

The error I'm getting currently is:

> reactions is not defined

Comment: Well... `reactions` is not defined.  What do you expect `if (reactions.cache.get("").count <= 0)` to do and why?  If there's no variable called `reactions`, what is this condition checking?

Comment: I thought 'reactions' was a part of discord.js (sorry I'm new with this) How else am I supposed to college the count of reactions? @David

Comment: Perhaps you're following a guide or tutorial somewhere which demonstrates?  I'm sure there is some built-in functionality for interacting with "reactions", but it's not built-in to the JavaScript language itself.  It'll need to be referenced from something/somewhere in the Discord framework.

Comment: I'm not following a guide, I'm doing it all from my own knowledge. And no I'm not using any thing else to be referenced @David

Comment: If you're looking for the amount of reactions of message, perhaps checking the properties of a message may help? i.e `message.reactions`

Answer (score 0):

`reactions` is not defined since (from the code you put in your question) the variable is never assigned. You need to [get the reactions of a message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions) or use a [Collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector). In the future provide more code.

Discord.js has a guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reactions) that explains reactions.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how I can get the amount of reactions on the message?

Comment: Also how do I use the reaction collector to give an end result?

Comment: I provided all the documentation links: [get message reatcions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions), [collector documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector), [how to use a collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors). As the documentation reads: `<message>.reactions.cache` and then do what you need with that. Hope this helps